# implementing twisted with tkinter UI

Tags: python, tkinter, twisted

I have been working on making a simple IM program and want there to be a ui with it to make it easier to work with. I know how to use tkinter well so that is why i want the ui to be tkinter, but im am new to twisted, and understand the basics of it, but I do not know how to implement it into the ui. This is my attempt at it, i have searched online for a long time but was unable to find anything simmilar to do what I am trying to do. The main problem I was running into earlier was having running to reactors, when trying to listen and send messages. One of my previous programs was able to just recieve messages but not send them back, so that is the main problem I am trying to fix. Thank you very much in advance.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint
from twisted.internet import tksupport, reactor, protocol
from Tkinter import *


class UI:

    def __init__(self, master):

        # set up start of screen
        self.root = master

        # set up frame
        self.frame = Frame(self.root, width=250, height=325)
        self.frame.pack_propagate(0)
        self.frame.pack()

        # set up Message box
        self.message_box = Text(self.frame, height=15, width=25, bg='white', bd=5, relief=RIDGE, state='disabled')
        self.message_box.pack(side=TOP)

        # set up entry box
        self.entry_box = Text(self.frame, height=2, width=25, bg='white', bd=5, relief=RIDGE)
        self.entry_box.bind('<Return>', self.send_message)
        self.entry_box.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        # set up label
        self.label = Label(self.frame, text='Enter a message')
        self.label.pack(side=BOTTOM)


    def send_message(self, event):

        message = self.entry_box.get(1.0, END)
        self.entry_box.delete(1.0, END)   


        point = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, "localhost", 1234)
        d = point.connect(GreeterFactory())
        d.sendMessage(message)

class Greeter(Protocol):
    def sendMessage(self, msg):
        self.transport.write(msg)

class GreeterFactory(Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Greeter()

class Listen(protocol.Protocol):

    def dataReceived(self, data):

        message = str(data)

        ui.message_box.config(state='normal')
        ui.message_box.insert(END, '%s\n' %(message))
        ui.message_box.config(state='disabled')

# start UI        
root = Tk()
root.tk_bisque()
root.title('Client Messager')
root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
ui = UI(root)
tksupport.install(root)

# start listneing
factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
factory.protocol = Listen
reactor.listenTCP(8000,factory)
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `point.connect()` returns a deferred, not a protocol instance. If you run the code it raises an exception on `d.sendMessage(message)`:

  ```
  d.addCallback(lambda p: p.sendMessage(message))
  ```
- `transport.write()` expects bytes, not a Unicode string:

  ```
  self.transport.write(msg.encode('utf-8'))
  ```
- `Listen.dataReceived()` might receive only partial message at a time. You could use `LineReceiver.lineReceived` instead to get the whole line at once. These methods receive bytes you should decode them to Unicode before passing to UI widgets.
- you send to `1234` port, but the server listens on `8000`. You probably meant to use the same port number here

There are other problems in your code.